SignalR negotiation with multiple server pods (load balancing)
I'm having a problem with SignalR in my .NET app.
There are two steps for connecting the frontend to the socket:
1º Send a HTTP POST request to negotiate(as I'm not skipping the negotiation) with the hub (get the token and the available transport types);
2º Start the websocket connection;
My problem is, I have the application hosted in the cloud (in containers), with load balancing. Every time that the backend application (hosting SignalR) has more than one pod(instance), it doesn't work properly. The first request works properly, returning the token and transport types. The second request, throw me a 404 with response "No Connection with that ID";
My guess is: as it has a loading balancing, the first step of the connection, the negotiation, is sent to server A. The second step, where it tries to make the connection to the socket, is sent to server B, that has not the token and the id of the connection and cannot validate it.
Negotiate request:

Negotiate response:

Connection to hub request:

Connection to hub response:

On local server or running the backend server in a single pod, it works fine.
I tried to implement redis as a backplane, but I don't think that it fix this error.

Sticky sessions are required when using SignalR with multiple servers.

I did set it to sticky sessions, but I'm afraid that even with this option, the first negotiation request is sent to one server and the second to another. That's what appears to be happening.

Are you using azure as your cloud provider? Then you can use Azure SignalR service. It can handle all load balancing scenarios by managing all the connectionIds and IP addresses. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/products/signalr-service/

if you are using sticky sessions, you need to use the actual ARRAffinity header sent during negotiate from the signalr server.

Initial request to negotiate/get transport types:
Server responds with ARRAffinity headers from all servers the request has executed on. This will include the actual server where signalr connection was created.
The response should look similar to
ARRAffinity: abc1 - domain - signalr server
ARRAffinity: def2 - domain - API gateway.

In the next request made to establish the websocket, set ARRAffinity as ABC1, not def2. This will fwd the request to the server where the connection id was actually created.



I had the same problem. You need to set session affinity cookie. For my case, here is my Arch
app gateway ---> ingress nginx ---> svc ---> pod

I fixed it by adding session affinity cookie in ingress nginx, for example:
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: ApplicationGatewayAffinity
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-path: /
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-samesite: None
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-secure: "true"

The last two line about cookie is for local development.
The root cause is the first negotiate request(POST) and the second websocket(GET) are handled by different pod, the token in the second request is issued by the first pod, but the second pod has NOT FOUND that token record, so return 404.
